# Visual studio 2019 Git Pull and Sync icon is not Showing in Git changes

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2019 for getting artifacts from a git server. I already downloaded GitHub extension for VS and merged correctly with the branch-dev. I can't able to Pull and Sync with already available code also the option not showing in Git changes..

[image]

Any idea for this behavior?

Comment: Does it appear if you enter a message?

Answer (score 0):

yes, this is new settings available under VS2019.

but you can change behavior by go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and uncheck "New Git user experience" and save changes.

[Git settings under tools menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AJvj.png)

Now you can see git options in team explorer.

[Team explorer git settings in Visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ruR4a.png)